# Should I commit dlls and generated bin files to repository on GitHub or just ignore them?

Tags: git, github, version-control, repository

I am using a private repository on GitHub to develop a project. The problem is that every time I do a commit, a bunch of bin files that I haven't manually modified get committed too. If I ignore them, will that cause any problems when someone else pull or clone the repo? Also if you can give me any best practices tips would be great.

[image]

On this commit for example I've only modified around 8 files, but 44 changes are being pushed to the repo. Most of them bin files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those files were never committed before, but are part of your index, you need to reset them (to remove them from the index)

```
git reset *.dll
git reset *.mdb
git reset *.apk
```

(If there were committed before, see "[Ignoring files](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/)")

Then you can add them to .gitignore

```
*.dll
*.mdb
*.apk
```

Check with git status that those files are not listed anymore.

Finally, you can `git add -A`, and `git commit`

Ignoring *generated* files won't be an issue for other users: they will rebuild them from the sources of the repo.

Regarding dlls, it is best to include only a [NuSpec](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/schema/nuspec) or a [`nuget.config`](http://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior) which will declare what you need to fetch said dll from Nuget.
See also "[The right way to restore NuGet packages](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/01/the-right-way-to-restore-nuget-packages.html)" from [David Ebbo](https://twitter.com/davidebbo), and [Nuget automatic restore](http://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/consume-packages/package-restore#migrating-to-automatic-restore).

Answer (score 4):

If the dll files and bin files are the **output of your build project**, it’s unnecessary to commit them, you can ignore them by `.gitignore` file and it has no effect for anyone who use the repo.

If the dll files are **3rd-party files** which used to support some functions of your project, you’d better put them in version control list.

Comment: is it a good practice to put 3rd party dlls in outside of the bin folder ?

Comment: I'm also curious in or outside?

Comment: You can do either ... as long as your team is consistent. If you put them in the `bin` folder, be sure to add an exception! For example, `!some-third-party.dll`